# Get rows of tensor that satisfy condition tensorflow

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

```
input_mb = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, 166, 1], name="input_minibatch")
```

Let's say there is the above code. I want to get the rows of the above minibatch tensor such that the first element of each retrieved row == a. How do I do this in Tensorflow? Also, how do you do this in Numpy?

Answer (score 0):

*(Given a value a)*

To achieve this in **numpy** you just have to write :

```
selected_rows = myarray[myarray[:,0]== a]
```

In **tensorflow**, use tf.where :

```
mytensor[tf.squeeze(tf.where(tf.equal(mytensor[:,0],a), None, None))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this on tensorflow:

```
tf.gather(mytensor, tf.squeeze(tf.where(tf.equal(mytensor[:,0],a), None, None)), axis=0)
```